# How do I get a notification when a Whatsapp friend comes online?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I want to know how I can get notifications whenever a certain contact comes online in Whatsapp? Is there any settings or hack I can do?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Whatsapp+. It doesn't require root. Besides giving the option of showing a toast notification when someone comes online, it has loads of other features, too. For example, it will show a contact's last seen time on the main screen right next to their name.